# Share an internet connection from a Windows 10 machine to a Linux machine via Ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, ethernet

I'm trying to share an internet connection from a windows 10 machine to a linux (lubuntu) machine via ethernet.

I have the following setup:
[Linux machine]----ethernet----[Windows 10 machine]----wifi----[router-modem-internet]

My windows machine sees the internet, but my Linux machine does not. Pretty sure the two machines can talk to each other.

I'm kind of poking around in the dark here, not sure what to try next. So far I have tried the following:

On Windows machine:
-Network Connections does show both my Wifi and my LAN (which it calls "Unidentified network")
- I've clicked on the network properties and selected "allow other users to connect through this computers internet connection" (I've tried this both on the Wifi network and the LAN)
- I've tried bridging the network connections
- If I run windows network diagnostics on the LAN I get "Local Area connection doesn't have a valid IP configuration

On linux machine: 
- If I ping google.com I get "Temporary failure in name resolution"
- I run ipconfig on the windows machine to find it's IP address on the LAN. Then I try to ping that from the linux machine, and that seems to work.

Comment: It's really easy to google what you want: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+10+bridge+internet+connection&ia=web

Comment: Thanks but I did google a lot. That's how I came up with all the things I listed to try, including bridging. That's why I came here to ask. To give it a fair go I followed the instructions in a few of the top links in your search but still no luck.